# Why this python code gives me output "False"?

Tags: python

I don't know the reason for this output("False"). Please explain.

```
sum=0
for i in range(10):
    sum+=0.1
print (sum==1.0)
```

Comment: @siavashk Nope.It reaches 1.0

Comment: @siavashk print `sum` after incrementing it or after the loop. The result I get is `0.9999999999999999`.

Comment: @siavashk, run the code first.

Comment: My bad everyone. It's been a long day and I put the print at the wrong place. I am deleting my comments to avoid misleading people.